# How to change text color of a MahApps TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro, tabitem

I use MahApps in a WPF application and I have serveral `TabControl`s.

**I found how to change font size with :**

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
       <Setter Property="controls:HeaderedControlHelper.HeaderFontSize" Value="12" />
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

I would like to modify the text color, too, but I don't find how to do it.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither `HeaderedControlHelper` nor `TabControlHelper` can be used to set the header brushes, as they are hard-coded in the control template of the default style for `TabItem`.

In order to change the header brushes, you have to copy the [default style for `TabItem` from GitHub](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.TabControl.xaml#L104) and adapt the `Foreground` brushes which determine the text color in all control states that you need. There are five sections where the foreground brushes are set.

1. Default foreground if not overridden by any other state.

   ```
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Text}" />
   ```
2. Foreground brush in the selected state of a tab.

   ```
   <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
      <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}" />
      <Setter TargetName="Underline" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(mah:TabControlHelper.UnderlineSelectedBrush), Mode=OneWay}" />
   </Trigger>
   ```
3. Foreground brush when a tab is not selected.

   ```
   <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
      <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Gray}" />
   </Trigger>
   ```
4. Foreground brush when the mouse is over the tab header.

   ```
   <Trigger SourceName="Border" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Gray.MouseOver}" />
      <Setter TargetName="Underline" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(mah:TabControlHelper.UnderlineMouseOverBrush), Mode=OneWay}" />
   </Trigger>
   ```
5. Foreground brush when the mouse is over the tab header but not selected.

   ```
   <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
         <Condition SourceName="Border" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
         <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Highlight}" />
      <Setter TargetName="Underline" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(mah:TabControlHelper.UnderlineMouseOverSelectedBrush), Mode=OneWay}" />
   </MultiTrigger>
   ```

Move your adapted style to a resource dictionary and reference the style by key explicitly or remove the `x:Key` to make it implicit so it will be applied to all tab items in scope automatically.

Comment: Hi an thanks for the answer. I tried to add it as dictionnary ressource but i have a tons of error when just compiling after just adding the dictionnary ressource : The name "TabControlHelper" doesn't exist in the "clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls" namespace.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni If you copy the style directly into a resource dictionary, you should add `xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"` as namespace, which resolves most errors. The last four errors for the `converters:IsNullConverter.Instance` are resolved by replacing the `converters` prefix with `mah`.

Comment: Thanks, i did it saddly i still have error with the xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Behaviors" & xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Converters" namespace and even with the mah.IsNullConverter.Instance

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni [Here](https://pastebin.com/rz1aW8ds) is an adapted sample without errors. Ignore or remove the `local` namespace. Try it and see if it works, if not, what errors do you get?

Comment: Thanks a lot, all is working :) Thanks for your help. MahApps is very nice, it's too bad we cannot directly modify these properties whitout using these way. Maybe in the futur ? Thanks again :)